# Java, If Statement. if it is true, could i have 2 separate equations to do if its true?

Tags: java

Okay so my question is pretty hard to understand sorry, so heres my question in greater detail.

Example code

```
    for (int i = 1; i<run1.length; i++)
    { if (run1[i]< iMin)
        iMin = run1[i];      //<-this is what im asking about
    }
```

is there a simple way of stating that IF it is true then?:
iMin= iScore + iMin and iMin = run1.

Because the problem is on the first loop, iRun= iMin.
2nd loop iRun has a new value that is lesser than Imin currently (iMin holds the lowest number i put in) and so iMin is replaced by a new lesser number. I would like to catch this old number and add it to a different variable.

Can this be done? Thank you

Thank Roddy of the Frozen Peas for answering my poorly worded question.

```
    if( x < min ) {
previousMin = min;
min = x;      <----- I was after if i could have a 2nd statement
```

}

sorry and thank you all

Comment: So complex explanation. Didn't get a thing. Please express in a better manner (examples may be?).

Comment: What is the iRun that you refer to? It's nowhere in your code.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, all you want is simply put two statements in the if clause which you do by enclosing them in curly braces such as: `if(run1[i]<iMin){iMin=run1[i];...}`

Comment: sorry guys for my bag wording but i found my answer. The code supplied from Roddy of the Frozen Peas showed me the answer.
        if( x < min ) {
    previousMin = min;    
    min = x;               <------what i was asking about, how to have
  }                                          a second 'statement' or whatever its called

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't store two different values in a single variable. You need two different variables.

```
int min = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
int previousMin = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
for( int x : numbers) {
  if( x < min ) {
    previousMin = min;
    min = x;
  }
}
```

Here I store the smallest value in the array in `min` and the previously found minimum in `previousMin`.

The point really is that you need to track the values separately.

---

If you just want to do a one-shot mathematical operation on finding a new max, and don't need to store the previous min value any longer, you can do so *prior* to assigning the new min value.

```
Integer min = null;
for ( int x : numbers ) {
  if( min == null || x < min ) {

    // if we're overriding a previously found min,
    // then min won't be null
    if( min != null ) {
      // do math with previous min
      sum += min;
    }

    // assign the new min
    min = x;
  }
}
```

Here I used Java's `Integer` wrapper class to track the minimum so I could distinguish between the scenario of finding the first minimum and finding subsequent ones. The `sum += min` is a trivial operation showing how you could do work using the previous min value prior to assigning the new one.

This second solution only works if you don't need to keep track of the previously identified value and just use it in an operation rather than persisting it.

Comment: in fact, you probably want them initialized to be large, right?

Comment: That would make sense, probably Integer.MAX_VALUE. It all depends on the data. Frankly it may be best to use null Integers, and update the if to be `min == null || x < min`, but I didn't want to over specify the details since the question was if two values could be stored, not how to determine if a number is the minimum.

Comment: Updated answer accordingly.